# How is measured the transmission rate of virusses?

Tags: disease-transmission, virus, measurement, database

I would like to know how is measured the transmission rate of viruses, for example, there is a 'normal' flu, his transmission rate is '1', but for a virus like H1N1 the transmission rate is '0.2' because it is harder to transmit.

-The values were just examples.

How is measured the transmission rate of virusses?

Is there some table with the diseases and their respective transmission rate?